# Retrieving Data from Firebase through GenericTypeIndicator

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to retrieve a certain level of data from my Firebase database however I am getting a warning

> Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Firstly my data is structured as such:

[image: First off my database is structured like this:]

And I am trying to just retrieve the fields immediately under "games" (i.e Method, and Oxley) and display them in a listview, and not retrieve the players of the games.

This is my code

```
private ListView lv;
List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
List<String> gameNames = new ArrayList<String>();

final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Games");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sessions);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.games);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            gameNames);

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,String prevChildKey){
            Game newGame = dataSnapshot.getValue(Game.class);
            gameNames.add(newGame.toString());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

}
```

And if it helps here is the code that puts the game into the database, I think it may have something to do with the "Map" type, because my list view worked just fine before that.

```
public void beginGame(View view) {
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();

        EditText gameNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gameName);
        String gameName = gameNameField.getText().toString().trim();
        Collections.shuffle(players);
        if (gameName.isEmpty()) {
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.toast_no_game_name, duration);
            toast.show();

        } else if (playerNames.size() < 2) {
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.toast_not_enough_players, duration);
            toast.show();

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
                if (i != (players.size() - 1)) {
                    players.get(i).target = players.get(i + 1);
                } else {
                    players.get(i).target = players.get(0);
                }
            }
            Game game = new Game(gameName, players);
            DatabaseReference gamesRef = ref.child("Games").child(gameName).child("players");
            Map<String, Player> gamePlayers = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
                Player currentPlayer = players.get(i);
                gamesRef.child(currentPlayer.getName()).setValue(currentPlayer);

            }
```

Comment: Did you post all the relevant code?  You say you have concerns about a Map type. but the only Map object is `gamePlayers`: `Map<String, Player> gamePlayers = new HashMap<>()`, and it is not used anywhere in the posted code.  Also, it would be helpful to see the declaration of `players` and the definition of class `Player`.

Comment: Please include how you defined the Game class, especially what kind of fields you declared. Its app-specific behavior does not matter here, so feel free to remove that beforehand.